# How to open multiple lightbox windows

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, lightbox

Is it possible or - this there a lightbox plugin that supports multiple windows to be opened paralell?

I.e. a quiz: an image in the left window - answers in the right window.

Comment: you could show both in the same lighbox window.

Comment: Hm yes i thought about that too. Can it have a transparent divider in the middle? Great would be if the windows pop-up with a short delay. Like Click -> Pop Window 1 ... Pop Window 2 .. :)

Comment: I actually have an working example here: http://ak.adartists-online.net/ak/adartists/?language=de but it works in flash

Answer (score 0):

What i would suggest is making one big lightbox appear and then change the content in that dynamically to suit what you wanna show. For an example if you wanna show 2 boxes but only 1 at load, then you could simple make the width of the lightbox the same as the combined with of your 2 content boxes. Then you simply position your elements inside the lightbox to suit it's state. For an example, if only one box is shown it will auto center it, but if 2 boxes shown it will then just add it to the right.

No need of multiple lightboxes :)